# Как организовать архитектуру приложения?

Tags: websocket, rmi, java, архитектура, чат

Привет!

Вчера намучился с этими вебсокетами, не хотели они работать. Когда запускал tomcat через IDEA, пришлось скачивать TomEE, в нём вроде работают. В итоге получился вот такой сервер:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/chat")
public class Chat {

    private String username = null;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void sendMessage(Session session, String msg) {

        JSONObject incoming = new JSONObject(msg);

        if (incoming.has("username")) {
            username = incoming.getString("username");
        }
        if (incoming.has("text")) {
            String text = incoming.getString("text");

            for (Session ss : session.getOpenSessions()) {
                try {
                    if (ss.isOpen()) {
                        ss.getBasicRemote().sendText(username + ":  " + text);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        ss.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Ну, тут вроде всё понятно, приходят JSON строки, если в ней есть имя (оно при подключении посылается), запоминаем имя, если переменная text, рассылаем этот текст во все открытые сессии.

Опытным путём установил, что объект класса Chat (*кстати, как правильно называется класс @ServerEndpoint?*) создаётся для каждого нового подключения и существует всё время, пока подключение активно.

**А вот в чём вопрос:** как привязать теперь это к моему главному серверу, ну, там, через обычные сокеты или через RMI?

**Для чего это надо:** допустим, я хочу наладить чат между двумя пользователями. Они подключаются, посылают свой логин/пароль, в @OnMessage, допустим, через RMI вызывается метод Authorize(String login, String pass, int sessionId), и где-то в памяти сервера sessionId связывается с конкретным пользователем. *Что теперь нужно сделать, чтобы когда пользователю пришло сообщение (событие на сервере), оно отправилось на клиент?*

P. S. Пока писал, возникла мысль передавать на сервер по RMI объект Session, правильная мысль?

P. P. S. Много текста получилось, извините. Может, мой вопрос ещё кому-то будет полезен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такую штуку я придумал:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/chat")
public class Chat {

    private static MainProcessor processor = null;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        if (processor == null) {
            processor = new MainProcessor();
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void sendMessage(Session session, String msg) {
        ...
    }
}
```

При первом подключении создаём объект класса MainProcessor и делаем в нем всё, что душе угодно.